# How to change font face of Webview in Android?

Tags: android, webview, font-face, custom-font

I want change the default font of webview to a custom font. I'm using webview in developing an bilingual browser app for Android.

I tried getting an instance of custom typeface by placing my custom font in assets. But still couldn't set webview's default font to my font.

This is what I tried:

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "myfont.ttf"); 
private WebView webview;
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setFixedFontFamily(font);
```

Can anyone correct this or suggest any other method to change webview's default font to a custom font?

Thanks!

Comment: Finally I realised that this can't be done.

Comment: check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344080/how-to-use-custom-font-with-webview/4836524#4836524

Comment: hi did u find any solution for this font face thing, I am trying for hindi font http://stackoverflow.com/q/5868198/501859. help me if u got the solution

Comment: @Dhanika how to solve this issue facing same issue.

Comment: Please refer this link for set custom font in the webview text ..http://stackoverflow.com/a/25692052/3921740[1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25692052/3921740

Answer (score 118):

There's a working example of this in [this project](https://github.com/mayooresan/Japs-Attack-Ceylon--Android-App). It boils down to:

1. In your `assets/fonts` folder, place the desired OTF or TTF font (here MyFont.otf)
2. Create a HTML file that you'll use for the WebView's content, inside the `assets` folder (here inside `assets/demo/my_page.html`):

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
   <style type="text/css">
   @font-face {
       font-family: MyFont;
       src: url("file:///android_asset/fonts/MyFont.otf")
   }
   body {
       font-family: MyFont;
       font-size: medium;
       text-align: justify;
   }
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>
   Your text can go here! Your text can go here! Your text can go here!
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
3. Load the HTML into the WebView from code:

   ```
   webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/demo/my_page.html");
   ```

Take note that injecting the HTML through `loadData()` is not permitted. [As per the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

> Note that JavaScript's same origin policy means that script running in a page loaded using this method will be unable to access content loaded using any scheme other than 'data', including 'http(s)'. To avoid this restriction, use loadDataWithBaseURL() with an appropriate base URL.

As @JaakL suggests in the comment below, for loading HTML from a string, you should instead provide the base URL pointing to your assets:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlData);
```

When referencing the font in `htmlData`, you may then simply use `/fonts/MyFont.otf` (omitting the base URL).

Comment: LoadData() does not work, but webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",... works fine. Then also font file reference as "/fonts/MyFont.otf" should work.

Comment: In my case , data is returning in the form of tags from ck editor(backend api)   <div style=\"text-align: center;\">
<span style=\"background-color: transparent;\">
<font color=\"#f20505\" size=\"5\" face=\"Comic Sans MS\">Please share your feedback with us<\/font>
<\/span>  I am setting it as webview.loadData() but its not taking fonts , Any solution ??

Comment: Comic Sans MS is not a font provided by Android. It will only work if you have defined the font face in CSS and provided the font file in your application's assets.

Comment: my font is located in the `res/font` folder. What would the path be then? I tried `file:///android_res/font/` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Wirling Did you get any solution or moved into assets folder?

Comment: @AnshulTyagi Unfortunately I didn't find a solution. So I moved the fonts to the assets folder.

Comment: I'm also struggling right now.

Answer (score 112):

**I am using this code** :

```
wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
String pish = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">@font-face {font-family: MyFont;src: url(\"file:///android_asset/font/BMitra.ttf\")}body {font-family: MyFont;font-size: medium;text-align: justify;}</style></head><body>";
String pas = "</body></html>";
String myHtmlString = pish + YourTxext + pas;
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,myHtmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: OMG! THIS is exactly what put us onto the trail of what was going wrong: as it turns out, Android 4.2 does NOT render the font if you add the "format('ttf')" behind the "src: url('...')" clause. Leave that out and the fonts are rendered beautifully. Tested with Google's own web fonts.

Comment: This is rocking solution, Thumbs up

Comment: loadDataWithBaseURL not working  on android 4.1 and 4.2 versions :(

Comment: didn't work for me in android 5.1 . I used (Dan Syrstad)'s answer. the difference is quotation `font-family: 'myface';`

Answer (score 53):

Even simpler, you can use the Asset URL format to reference the font. No programming needed!

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'myface';
   src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/myfont.ttf'); 
} 

body { 
   font-family: 'myface', serif;
```

...

Comment: If I place the `.ttf` and `.html` file in the same directory and load it up in the Android browser, it works. However in my app's WebView, while the CSS shows, the text appears in Android's default font despite adding the `.ttf` to the project's `assets/fonts` folder. I'm testing on 2.3.5, but building against 2.1. Could that be the problem, or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I found a resolution: if you create an HTML file and place it in the assets, loading it via `view.loadUrl()` works, whereas `view.loadData()` does not. I have no clue why the latter doesn't.

Comment: A lil' late, but it works with view.loadDataWithBaseUrl(null, content, mime, enconding, null)

Answer (score 29):

It can be done in Android. I took three days to solve this issue. But now it seems very easy.
Follow these steps to set custom font for Webview

1.Add your font to assets folder
2.Copy the font to application's files directory

```
private boolean copyFile(Context context,String fileName) {
        boolean status = false;
        try { 
            FileOutputStream out = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            InputStream in = context.getAssets().open(fileName);
            // Transfer bytes from the input file to the output file
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            // Close the streams
            out.close();
            in.close();
            status = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in copyFile:: "+e.getMessage());
            status = false;
        }
        System.out.println("copyFile Status:: "+status);
        return status;
    }
```

3.You have to call above function only once (you have to find some logic for this).

```
copyFile(getContext(), "myfont.ttf");
```

4.Use the below code to set value for your webview. Here I am using CSS to set font.

```
private String getHtmlData(Context context, String data){
    String head = "<head><style>@font-face {font-family: 'verdana';src: url('file://"+ context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+ "/verdana.ttf');}body {font-family: 'verdana';}</style></head>";
    String htmlData= "<html>"+head+"<body>"+data+"</body></html>" ;
    return htmlData;
 }
```

5.You can call the above function as below

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, getHtmlData(activity,htmlData) , "text/html", "utf-8", "about:blank");
```

Comment: Hi! I tried this approach but the WebView still doesn't load my font. Is there anything special you did? Thanks!

Comment: how to do that for html http://stackoverflow.com/q/5868198/501859. help me if u got the solution

Comment: i am having the font in asset folder and changing css with that complete path of font and font family name in body ,and after modification i am loading the content again but can 't see the font change effect immediately

Answer (score 14):

i done this by upper answers with this additions:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",
                            WebClient.getStyledFont(someText),
                            "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null, "about:blank");
```

and then use `src: url("file:///android_asset/fonts/YourFont...`

```
public static String getStyledFont(String html) {
    boolean addBodyStart = !html.toLowerCase().contains("<body>");
    boolean addBodyEnd = !html.toLowerCase().contains("</body");
    return "<style type=\"text/css\">@font-face {font-family: CustomFont;" +
            "src: url(\"file:///android_asset/fonts/Brandon_reg.otf\")}" +
            "body {font-family: CustomFont;font-size: medium;text-align: justify;}</style>" +
            (addBodyStart ? "<body>" : "") + html + (addBodyEnd ? "</body>" : "");
}
```

thanks to everybody:)

Comment: Perfect Answer!!

Answer (score 7):

If you are putting fonts under `res/font` like me, then you can change the dir to the following:-

```
@font-face {
     font-family: yourfont;
     src: url("file:///android_res/font/yourfont.ttf")
}
        
body {
     font-family: yourfont;
}
```

Comment: This avoided me to have the same font 2 times. Thanks!

Comment: Not working for me.

Comment: This worked but I also had to use the `loadDataWithBaseUrl` like in the other answers

Answer (score 6):

Many of the above answers work lie a charm if you have your content in your assets folder.

However, if you like me want to download and save all your assets from a server to your internal storage you can instead use `loadDataWithBaseURL` and use a reference to your internal storage as the baseUrl. Then all files there will be relative to the loaded html and are found and used correctly.

In my internal storage I have saved the following files:

- IndigoAntiqua2Text-Regular.ttf
- style.css
- image.png

Then I use the following code:

```
WebView web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webby);
//For avoiding a weird error message
web.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

String webContent = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset=\"UTF-8\"><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"style.css\"></head>"
                            + "<body><img src='image.png' width=\"100px\"><div class=\"running\">I am a text rendered with INDIGO</div></body></html>";

String internalFilePath = "file://" + getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/";
web.loadDataWithBaseURL(internalFilePath, webContent, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

The CSS file used in the above html (style.css):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyCustomRunning';
  src: url('IndigoAntiqua2Text-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype');
}

.running{
    color: #565656;
     font-family: "MyCustomRunning";
     font-size: 48px;
}
```

I have only tried this while targeting minSdkVersion 19 (4.4) so I have no idea if it works on other versions

Answer (score 6):

```
 webview= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
 String myCustomStyleString="<style type=\"text/css\">@font-face {font-family: MyFont;src: url(\"file:///android_asset/fonts/iranian_sans.ttf\")}body,* {font-family: MyFont; font-size: 13px;text-align: justify;}img{max-width:100%;height:auto; border-radius: 8px;}</style>";
 webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", myCustomStyleString+"<div style=\"direction:rtl\">"+intentpost.getStringExtra("content")+"</div>", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Comment: Please improve your question adding an explanation of what you're doing.

Answer (score 5):

Response compatible with Android 11 (API 30) or above.

I saw a lot of answers, but none of them was working on Android 11+. For me, the solution was: [WebAssetLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/webkit/WebViewAssetLoader).

```kotlin
val assetLoader = WebViewAssetLoader.Builder()
    .addPathHandler(
        "/res/", 
        WebViewAssetLoader.ResourcesPathHandler(context))
    .build()
```

In my case, the font is in `res/font` folder.

```kotlin
webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
    ...
    override fun shouldInterceptRequest(
        view: WebView,
        request: WebResourceRequest
    ): WebResourceResponse? {
        return assetLoader.shouldInterceptRequest(request.url)
    }
}
```

Load the HTML content using `loadDataWithBaseURL`.

```kotlin
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(
    "https://appassets.androidplatform.net",
    getStyledHtmlContent(),
    "text/html",
    "UTF-8",
    null
)
```

The `getStyledHtmlContent` returns your HTML content.

```kotlin
private fun getStyledHtmlContent() =
    """
    <html>
    <head>
        <style>
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'AnyNameYouWant';
                src: url('https://appassets.androidplatform.net/res/font/yourfont.otf');
            }
            body {
                font-family: AnyNameYouWant;
                line-height: 1.5;
                text-align: justify;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>Content of your page</body>
    </html>
    """.trimIndent()
```

Answer (score 3):

You need not use local ttf file to set webview font for android, It will increase the whole app size.

you can also use online fonts like google's font... It will help to reduce your apk size.

For example: visit the below URL 
https://gist.github.com/karimnaaji/b6c9c9e819204113e9cabf290d580551#file-googlefonts-txt

You will found necessary info to use this font. then create a String like below

```
String font = "@font-face {font-family: MyFont;src: url(\"here you will put the url of the font which you get previously\")}body {font-family: MyFont;font-size: medium;text-align: justify;}";
```

then load the webview like this

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("about:blank", "<style>" +font+</style>" + "your html contnet here", "text/html", null, null);
```

done. You will able to load the font from the external source in this way.

Now whats about the app font, it doesn't make sense to use 1 font for the webview and different font for the whole app. So you can use [Downloadable Fonts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts) in your app which also uses external sources for loading fonts in the app.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using CSS. I did it with an app but it won't work in Android 2.1 as there is an known bug with Android browser 2.1.

Comment: Can you add link add the link to the known issue.?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is it needs to be in a folder, try putting "./myfont.ttf" instead, if not put the font inside a folder in assets like "fonts/myfont.ttf" that will work for sure.

Answer (score 1):

test it, work for me like a charm :

```
   private void setResult() {

        String mimeType = "text/html;charset=UTF-8";
        String encoding = "utf-8";
        String htmlText = htmlPrivacy;

        String text = "<html><head>"
                + "<style type=\"text/css\">@font-face {font-family: MyFont;src: url(\"file:///android_asset/fonts/iy_reg.ttf\")}body{font-family: MyFont;color: #666666}"
                + "</style></head>"
                + "<body>"
                + htmlText
                + "</body></html>";

        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text, mimeType, encoding, null);
    }
```

Comment: This is simple 

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView library.

in html data :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: MyFont;
    src: url("file:///android_asset/fonts/font1.ttf")
}
body {
    font-family: MyFont;
    font-size: medium;
    text-align: justify;
}
</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;  charset=utf-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>

    ------ YOUR_CONTENT ------

</body>

</html>
```

in xml :

```
<im.delight.android.webview.AdvancedWebView
    android:id="@+id/advanced_web_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

in java :

```
advancedWebView = findViewById(R.id.advanced_web_view);
advancedWebView.loadHtml(htmlData, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");
```

Answer (score -3):

This is how do you load htmlData in a webview:

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, getHtmlData(activity,**htmlData**) , "text/html", "utf-8", "about:blank");
```

where `getHtmlData(activity,**htmlData**)` returns a string of html code.