# Android: WebView with Custom font

Tags: android, fonts, webview

I want to know is it possible to make a webview to load foreign language/font web site.
Let's say i want to load a URL which contains non-standard unicode font (they have their own font. I can download the font and use it.)

Right now, I know we can do this if both "html" and "font" file are located in the same folder under "Asset". Yes, this display the character correctly. I refer from this link >> [How to change font face of Webview in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900658/how-to-change-font-face-of-webview-in-android)

However, if I navigate to real web site URL from my asset folder html file, it will not render the font correctly.

Is there any way to achieve it?
By injecting some html tags or totally can't achieve it????

I also try google but all I get is above example with local HTML file with font.
Any suggestions or reference links are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: you can zoomIn and zoomOut for increasing font

Comment: Sorry TofeeqAhmad, may be I used the wrong words. The text is not display correctly like my local HTML file.

Comment: if you are using custom HTML file in webview.Then make sure that you are using tag that support by android Webview.Otherwise it will not show original effect.Like android does not all html tag

Comment: Found an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19267006/custom-font-for-webview-android