# custom font for webview android

Tags: android, android-webview, font-face

I use a webview in my app and i want display text in farsi language with custom font .I place my font in asset folder and write a method for place text in webview but in api8 that dont support farsi language .it dispaly unknown characters instead of my text and in apies that support farsi language it dont display my text by custom font and it display my text by default font .what is wrong in my method.thanks
my method

```
  public void setText(String text)
{
    String style2="<style type=\"text/css\">@font-face {font-family: 'myface';src: url('file:///android_asset/BYekan.ttf'); } body {font-family: 'myface';}</style>";
    this.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/BYekan.ttf","<html  dir=\"rtl\"><head><meta content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" http-equiv=\"Content-Type\"/>"+style2+"</head><body>"+text+"</body></html>","text/html","UTF-8",null);
    setClickable(false);
    setLongClickable(false);
    setFocusable(false);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
}
```

Comment: just a guess , try file:///android_asset as your base folder rather than file:///android_asset/BYekan.ttf

Comment: I test it but dont work :( @HussainAkhtarWahid

Answer (score 1):

Your style should look something like this:

```
@font-face{ 
font-family:myface;
font-weight:normal;
font-style:normal;
src:url('file:///android_asset/BYekan.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```