# How to make the font size to look the same in webview and textview?

Tags: android, webview, textview, font-size

I have ListView which contains many records with TextViews and WebViews. And i want to make them looks identical. But font size in TextView and WebView looks different on some devices (depends on screen size). 
For TextView I use sp units for WebView I tried to use setDefaultFontSize and setTextSize.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To set Custom font(s) in your Android application

To do this, simply create an assets/ folder in the project root, and put your fonts (in TrueType, or TTF, form) in the assets. You might, for example, create assets/fonts/ and put your TTF files in there:

```
 TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.custom); 
  Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/HandmadeTypewriter.ttf"); 
  tv.setTypeface(face);
```

Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900658/how-to-change-font-face-of-webview-in-android) to change the font in webview.