# How to set a font in Android WebView

Tags: android, webview

I read about this over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900658/how-to-change-font-face-of-webview-in-android)

But my questions is whether we can use SetStandardFontFamily command to set a font?

```
      mWebView.getSettings().setStandardFontFamily
```

Comment: What is the point of these ? I mean what do you want to do ?

Comment: I want to display the text in Arial font in the WebView.Currently,It's not getting displayed