# Phonegap Android - Helvetica/Arial font

Tags: android, cordova, fonts

I have an application in Android - I am using Phonegap - where I have to use "Arial" or "Helvetica" font. Everything is fine but 'g' looks like 'g' in Times new Roman:

http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Times_New_Roman

and I want to have Helvetica/Arial 'g' look:

http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helvetica

I checked on several phones/Android versions. None can read Helvetica/Arial 'g' look normal :(

I also tried to import TTF manually and adding it to project but it wasn't working either :(

Any help here?

P.S. sorry for English

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900658/how-to-change-font-face-of-webview-in-android

Comment: new font in ICS has that g http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roboto