# How can I provide custom font support for Webview in Android for random websites in specific languages?

Tags: android, fonts, webview

I want to add certain font support for the Android webview so when a user visit sites that are using that font, to display the font instead of boxes.I checked the whole Stack Overflow, but there they have answers for the sites that are stored in the assets or to a specific site with CSS. here I am not having the control of the website only the webview. Is there any way I can make the android webview support language we provide using tff file? 
And another thing it must not related to the system, but only inside the app.Also someone asked the same question but no answer yet so thought of asking again.
Thanx in Advance

Comment: Did u find the solution?

Comment: Nope, but you can check out this question this may be helpful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900658/how-to-change-font-face-of-webview-in-android