# Add custom font for android webview

Tags: android, unicode, webview

I want to develop a simple android web browser app that support a Unicode font I provide. I did some research but I couldn't find a successful method to add a custom font for a android `WebView`. There are some solutions to add custom fonts for a `WebView` but they are all based on adding font in the `CSS`. but since I don't have control over the page I load inside the WebView is there a method to add a font directly to the `WebView` like `setTypaFace()` method for `TextView`.?

here is the code i have used so far to add custom font for webview:

```
package com.example.sinhalafontrendering;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.sinhalafontrendering.R.id;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FontUtils.setCustomFont(findViewById(id.txtHelloWorld), getAssets());
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "iskpota.ttf");
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(id.txtHelloWorld);
        tv.setText("ශ්‍රී ලංකා, \n ");
        //tv.setTypeface(tf,0);

        String html = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">@font-face { font-family: MyCustomFont; src: url(\"Bamini.eot\") /* EOT file for IE */}@font-face { font-family: MyCustomFont; src: url(\"file:///android_asset/iskpota.ttf\") /* TTF file for CSS3 browsers */}body { font-family: MyCustomFont, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: medium;color: black}</style></head><body><LI><a href=\"http://www.thelastrow.lk/\">ශ්‍රී ලංකා;</a></LI></UL></div></body></html>";

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webGoogle);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        //mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/a.html");
        mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("www.thelastrow.lk", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have any access to  the website I want to load inside `WebView`. It should act like a simple browser window. but I don't know whether I can add `CSS` for a website I load inside a `WebView`.

Comment: i mean who have u loaded data to webview using load method??? if yes then u can add css in inside webview as well as custom fonts

Comment: I have tried to load custom font using `CSS` as mentioned here by @binary [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900658/how-to-change-font-face-of-webview-in-android?rq=1) but it didn't gave me the expected results. as mentioned I tried it with `loadBaseUrl()`  method like mentioned in below but no resusts :/

`webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("https://www.google.lk/", getHtmlData(MainActivity.this,""), "text/html", "utf-8", "about:blank");`

Comment: Is there anyone who can give solution for my matter :(

Comment: Please refer this link for set custom font in the webview text ..http://stackoverflow.com/a/25692052/3921740[1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25692052/3921740

Answer (score 0):

> It worked with loadDataWithBaseURL!
>
> For this example I changed the CSS to:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'feast';
    src: url('fonts/feasfbrg.ttf');
}

body {font-family: 'feast';}
```

> Then use the assets path as the base url:

```
loadDataWithBaseURL("www.google.com",myhtml,"text/html","utf-8",null);
```

Comment: So where can I add a custom url like _www.google.com_ to load that site with the font I add.?

Comment: It still doesen't load the url I set inside the web view. can you please post the full example...

Comment: Its working when I'm loading locally defined html file but its not working when Im trying to load a webpage from internet. Is there any other method to add custom font for a `WebView`.?

Comment: @Sajirupee hi kindly provide me time for today will post a solution for you 2moro in morning surly

Comment: Hi, Did you found a solution for my problem.?

Comment: @Sajirupee oops u still didnt find solution..sorry i forgot..i will hep u today

Comment: is it possible for u to add project.rar to mailid will just debug and post u back with solution

Comment: Hi, I have uploaded my project to mediafire. [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/o5fnhlggji5q9cz/SinhalaFontRendering.rar) is the link. sorry I couldn't do it sooner. hope you can find a solution. :)

Comment: @Sajirupee hey kindly dont post the code publicly u can mail sorry i forgot ur issue