# Add Font Family And Gravity Right To Html

Tags: android, html

Hello i have this html from webservices and i load it into web view ,, its working good ,, now i need to add my font to this , and make its gravity right !

```
 BodyNot = "<html> <head> <style> body { background-color: clear !important; } p,div,span,li { color:black; font-size:17px !important;background-color: clear !important;} embed, iframe, object, video {height: 160px; width: 355.0px;} img { height: 160px; width: 355.0px; } </style> </head> <body><p>" +
                            BodyNot +
                            "</p>" +
                            "</div></p></body> </html>";


                    serviceWebView.loadData(BodyNot, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
                    serviceWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                    serviceWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little bit guessing but I think that changing `<p>` to `<p align="right">` will do the job.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18183768/2600197 and read the whole thread because there are problems with _some_ fonts.