# android- font face is not changing on webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I need to change webview font face , I've searched and I used this but it didn't change the font , I've the font file in asset folder :

```
wb.loadData(
            "<html><head><style>@font-face { font-family: myface;src: url('file:///android_asset/yekan.ttf');" +
            "BODY, HTML {background: transparent;  } body,div {  font-family: myface;} </style></head><body><div style='text-align: justify; line-height: 23px;float:right' dir='rtl'>"
                    + text + "</div></body></html>",
            "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
```

is it wrong or webview couldn't change the font face ?

thanks

Comment: Better to crate your own CSS and HTML and load it from Assets....

Comment: follow this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900658/how-to-change-font-face-of-webview-in-android

Comment: did u getting any error.?

Comment: If I were you then I would have created HTML file and loaded it in webview.

Comment: thanks for the reply , the text changes , it comes from the activity and it's not static , is there any way ?

Comment: @prabhakaran no error , it just don't change the font-face

Answer (score 0):

**change**

`url('file:///android_asset/yekan.ttf')`

**to**

`url(\"file:///android_asset/yekan.ttf\")`

Comment: I'll check it , I'll post the result , Thanks anyway