# Setting font for Android WebView

Tags: android, css, webview, fonts

I have some webViews and I simply want to use "Tahoma" font for them. There are some questions about how to change font but none of them really work! This was my idea from answers: (Which works on Browsers NOT on Android)

Style I used on index.html:

```
 @font-face{
    font-family: 'tahoma';
    src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/tahoma.ttf');}  


 // tahoma.ttf is located on asset folder in my project
 // body{font-family: 'tahoma';}
```

Web view code:

```
rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page1, container, false);

 WebView timingView1= (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.TimingWebView);
 timingView1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

Comment: What do you mean "works on browsers"? What font shows on Android?

Comment: This is html and it works fine on browsers!

Comment: Sorry, read too quick... What shows on Android?

Comment: The problem is I can't change Android's default font on my app !!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900658/how-to-change-font-face-of-webview-in-android