# Customs font in webview in android application

Tags: android, webview, fonts

How to create webview with custom font.
Webview load external link ("www.example.com").This site is showed 
with custom font in my android application.

Thanks for all answer.

Comment: look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900658/how-to-change-font-face-of-webview-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Put you ttf file in Asset
and try this

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: typeface;
    src: url("file:///android_asset/fonts/typeface.otf")
}
body {
    font-family: typeface;
    font-size: medium;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```