# How to change Character Set of webview in android?

Tags: android, webview

How can I change character set of a html page from android on click? Let's say, there is a button to change the character set. On click of that button, it will change the character set from English to Chinese in WebView.

Comment: charset is not font.

Comment: sorry for the mistake..how to change that?

Comment: i dont know if it will work but on textview  i used this textview.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

Comment: or you can check this out 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900658/how-to-change-font-face-of-webview-in-android

Comment: thank you..but i am not sure that the example will help me.. because in my webview, i need to load html link and there will two buttons in my app to change the charsets. let's say on button click, some text in the webview will be changed