# Change font html in webview Android

Tags: java, android, html, webview, fonts

I'm displaying some html text coming from an ePub file inside my Android application through a WebView. However I'd like to set the font used no matter the font used in the ePub file. This is my activity code:

```
public class ContentViewActivity extends Activity {
    WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        String displayString = getIntent().getExtras().getString("display");
        if(displayString != null)
            webView.loadData(displayString, "text/html", "utf-8");
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried using websettings or a base url as suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900658/how-to-change-font-face-of-webview-in-android) using:

```
if(displayString != null) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/my_page.html");
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/html/my_page.html", displayString, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
    }
```

with

```html
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: MyFont;
    src: url("file:///android_asset/fonts/bookerly.ttf")
}
body {
    font-family: MyFont;
    font-size: medium;
    text-align: justify;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
Your text can go here
</body>
</html>
```

however when I run it, it seems to be ignoring the base URL and simply displaying the original html.
Is there a way to fix it or another way to proceed?

Thanks in advance,

PS: Of course I cannot change previously the CSS of the ePub file.