# Set the webview font to be the same as the system font

Tags: android

[image: toolbar and webview]

As yo can see in the picture the system font is different than the webview one. I'm not using font-type in the css file and I have this webview settings

```
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I may be late, but would this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57229260/11023871) do what you need?

Comment: No, it  isn't what I am looking for