# How to reload fragment when button clicked

Tags: java, android

I want to refresh fragment by clicking retry button in onCreateView.
If my internet is disconnected it must return fragment_no_internet_error layout. There is a button to reload fragment.

It gives me the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ir.hamedanmelk.hamedanmelk, PID: 21310
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.mFragmentManager' on a null object reference
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.detach(BackStackRecord.java:220)
```

my OnCreateView:

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v;
    CheckConnectivity checkConnectivity=new CheckConnectivity();
    if(!checkConnectivity.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())) {
        v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_no_internet_error, container, false);
        Button retrybutton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.no_internet_fragment_button_retry);
        retrybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Fragment frg = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.HelpFragment);
                final FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.detach(frg);
                ft.attach(frg);
                ft.commit();
            }
        });
        return v;
    }


    v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_f_a_q, container, false);
    mwebview = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webview_f_a_q);
    WebSettings webSettings=mwebview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    //TODO Change FontFace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900658/how-to-change-font-face-of-webview-in-android
    mwebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

    return v;
 }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: to reload webview in my fragment, when internet is available.

Comment: Then why you need to reload the whole fragment? When you just can reload the webview?

Comment: when device get internet ,user click on button to reload WebView. also i have some fragments that needs to load element's values from internet. i'm trying to make **device is offline error** fragment

Comment: Don't do that. Just add the view on top of it and set its Visibility according to your condition. Reloading the whole fragment just for the sake of the error message is not worth it.

Comment: many thanks, this is great way. i'll do this

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code. Becuase I think the issue is with API level

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = mActivity.getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
                transaction.setReorderingAllowed(false);
            }
            transaction.detach(this).attach
                    (this).commit();
```

Comment: What API  level you are using?

Comment: compileSdkVersion 29

Comment: Okay, if the problem is still coming use another way, Like call the activity again from the fragment. what this gonna do is when you call activity the activity of runs oncreate method and your fragment will be called and it is the updated fragment.  you can pass data from a fragment to that activity and use if-else statement for again calling the fragment if you don't wanna call that fragment every time when that activity is called.

Comment: i'll try that,تشکر

Answer (score 0):

try this.
in your fragment

```
 ((MainActivity)getActivity()).reload()
```

in your MainActivity

```
void reload(){
    final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    // R.id.fragment_layout is your fragment container view
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_layout, instanceFragment);
    ft.commit()
}
```

Comment: thanks to answering, i try this. it has error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f09007e (ir.hamedanmelk.hamedanmelk:id/faq_fragment_framelayout).

Comment: "faq_fragment_framelayout" is my framelayout id