# Arabic Font in android webview?

Tags: android, fonts, webview, arabic

We have site urls having arabic language we want to display as it is in android webview but it is not showing as correctly it is showing in reverse. Can you help me????

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple solution of it. As correct order letters display in reverse order. Why not we write reverse letters?
This link will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/13562693/1547539

Answer (score 3):

Just set the encoding : 
YourWebView.loadData(YourContentHtml, "text/html; **charset=UTF-8**", null);

Answer (score 2):

I fully understand your issue, you mean:

```
  [أحمد] Would show as [دمحا]
```

I am afraid this is not possible, I have seen some post around all confirm that can't be done in the mean time.

> Android has the ability to use custom TTFs in views (though it's kind of a kludge, example on how to use custom typefaces in the API Demos), but I'm not sure how to extend this to WebView, or whether it's even possible. [custom font with Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344080/how-to-use-custom-font-with-webview/1350048#1350048)

Also see: [font face of Webview in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900658/how-to-change-font-face-of-webview-in-android)