# android : i want use my custom font with WebViewb

Tags: android, css, fonts, android-webview, android-fonts

i want use my custom font with WebViewb
my html file loaded in webView but still without font
my font has Unicode characters
i work on android 2.2

```
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/P_007.html");
```

my css:

```
<STYLE type="text/css">
 @font-face {
    font-family: AQF_P007_HA;
    src: url("AQF_P007_HA.TTF");    
}
body {
    font-family: AQF_P007_HA;    
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: black;    
    font-size: medium;
    mso-font-charset: 0
}
</STYLE>
```

Comment: What should that code section represent?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution is document here:  [How to use custom font with WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344080/how-to-use-custom-font-with-webview)

is this similar to what you tried to use in your html file? 
With the url relative to your assets folder in this case?

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'AQF_P001_HA';
   src: url('AQF_P001_HA.TTF');
}

body {font-family: 'AQF_P001_HA';}
```

Comment: "failed"? What do you mean by "failed"? Please provide more information about what happened when you tried.

Answer (score 0):

my problem was MyFont.TTF but it must be MyFont.ttf
ttf is different from TTF in linux/android.
:-)
[android : html loaded without font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859032/android-html-loaded-without-font/9859057#comment12569733_9859057)