# android : html loaded without font

Tags: android, css, android-webview, android-fonts

my html file loaded in webView but still without font
my font has Unicode characters
i work on android 2.2

```
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/P_007.html");
```

my css:

```
<STYLE type="text/css">
 @font-face {
    font-family: AQF_P007_HA;
    src: url("AQF_P007_HA.TTF");    
}
body {
    font-family: AQF_P007_HA;    
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: black;    
    font-size: medium;
    mso-font-charset: 0
}
</STYLE>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

copy font to a directory in asset folder like "fonts" and use this instead:

```
<STYLE type="text/css">
 @font-face {
    font-family: AQF_P007_HA;
    src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/AQF_P007_HA.TTF');  
}
body {
    font-family: AQF_P007_HA;    
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: black;    
    font-size: medium;
    mso-font-charset: 0
}
</STYLE>
```

Comment: @Ahmed do you check mistakes like AQF_P007_HA.ttf

Comment: ttf is different from TTF in linux/android. are you checked letter case of whole font name?

Comment: Thanks a lot,  
This was really my problem, but I did not know this