# How to display hindi font in Android webview

Tags: android, html, css

How can we display hindi in android webview for this i got sample from github but that is for tamil,there  using content like this :

jpUkiy nfhOk;G Fz;LtPr;R epfo;Tfisg; ghu;f;f Kd;du; ,e;j epfo;tpd; jhf;fj;ijNa khw;wpaikj;j xUtiug; gw;wp rpy tupfs; vOjNtz;Lk;.

ypadhu;l; gpu;rhy; (Leonard Birchall) xU fNdba tpkhd Xl;b. rpWtajpy; ,Ue;Nj ,tupw;F gwf;Fk; Mir. xe;jhupNah khdpyj;jpy; gpwe;j ,tu; 1933 ,y; Nuhay; fNdba ,uhZtf; fy;Y}upapy; gbj;Jg; gl;lk; ngw;whu;. 1937 ,y; jdJ gapw;rpia Kbj;J fNdba Nwhay; tpkhdg; gilapy; tpkhd Xl;bahf ,ize;J nfhz;lhu;.

n\l;yhd;l; jPTfspy; jdJ gzpia Vw;Wf; nfhz;l ypNahdhl; gpd;du; Ig;ghdpau;fs; njd; fpof;F Mrpa ehLfisf; ifg;gw;wj; njhlq;fpaJk; ,yq;iff;F khw;wg;gl;lhu;. ,yq;ifapy; gwe;J fz;fhzpg;Gr; nra;Ak; gzpapy; ,tu;

4 Vg;uy; 1942 md;W ypadhu;l; nfhf;fiy gpuNjrj;jpy; ,Ue;J gwf;Fk; glF (mJjhd; ePupy; jiuapwq;Fk; tpkhdk;) fl;lyPdhtpy; Vwpg; gwf;fj; njhlq;fpdhu;. Rkhu; thdj;jpy; vl;L kzp Neuq;fs; Rw;wp fz;fhzpg;G gzpapy;

ngupa Ig;ghdpaf; flw;gilj; njhFjp xd;W ,yq;if Nehf;fp tpiue;Jnfhz;bUe;jJ. ,jpy; Ie;J tpkhde; jhq;fpf; fg;gy;fSk; ,Ue;jJ. gu gug;ghd ypadhl; jdJ tpkhdj;jpy; ,Ue;j rf tPuu;fs; %yk; jiuf;F jftiy tpiue;J njuptpj;jhu;.

,tu;fspd; tpkhdj;ijf; fz;l Ig;ghdpa fg;gy; jkJ fg;gypy; ,Ue;J jhf;Fjy; tpkhdj;ij Vtp ypadhu;l;bd; tpkhdj;ij Nehf;fpr; Rlj;njhlq;fpaJ. ntWk; fz;fhzpg;G tpkhdk; vd;gjdhy; jpUg;gpr; rz;il $lg; Nghl Kbahky; R+L gl;L flypy; tPo;e;jJ ypadhu;l; gadpj;j fl;lyPdh ,uf tpkhdk;.

what is the format this how can we get this for particular text is there any converter ?
please help me on this..

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: i am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the hindi font, whichever you want to use in the `asset` folder of your project and from there you can use the font using `css`.
The detailed explanation is posted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344080/how-to-use-custom-font-with-webview)

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,in assets folder we need to keep .ttf file ,in my question they have used some convertion for required language the above data is for tamil ,what i need exactly is how they are converting that and on which basis and what is that format.

Comment: You want it in Tamil or in Hindi? If you want it in Hindi, just put Hindi font in asset and use it in css. Same with Tamil.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, do you have any sample to display hindi font in webview can you please share..

Comment: Sorry don't have any code for that, though I used it. Check the link I posted in my answer. It'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

You gonna have to use following CSS hack :) Make sure to use non-unicode font. Unicode fons fails in it.

```
@font-face {
 font-family: MyCustomFont;
 src: url("file:///android_asset/Bamini.ttf") /* TTF file for CSS3 browsers */
}
```

and

```
body {
 font-family: MyCustomFont, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: medium;
 color: black
}
```

Refer my opensource project @ [GitHub for detail informaion](https://github.com/mayooresan/Japs-Attack-Ceylon--Android-App/blob/master/assets/japs/Index.html).

You can find many online font converters. For example I have used Bamini font converter available at [Suratha's site](http://www.suratha.com/uni2bam.htm)

Good luck.