# How to install an additional font in the root directory on an android device

Tags: android, fonts, android-webview, android-fonts

I have developed an application which contains a WebView for loading additional URL contents, but I have an issue.
The issue is that when I load a local language URL, some devices don't support local languages special characters, so some empty squares are shown.

How can I load an additional font in my application or device?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344080/how-to-use-custom-font-with-webview)

Answer (score 0):

Custom fonts are not that easy in android. You will need some .ttf files, which You must load at runtime as typeface.
This link has nice information, also about best practices, on how to deal with custom fonts properly.
Check out:
[Android - Using Custom Font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651086/android-using-custom-font)

Comment: i want to set font on webview buddy not text box so type face does not work on it

Answer (score 0):

If your webview is showing an online page (as opposed to a html file which is compiled into the assets somewhere, like Cordova/phonegap does), you perhaps should look at using a web font in the css. The easiest thing to do is uses google have a few hosted, see:

https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#Quick_Start

http://www.google.com/fonts (is the full list of fonts)

Hope that helps. (other webfont options are available).