# Persian font in android App

Tags: android, css, cordova

I create application for android with phonegap.

Front-end of app designed with html, css and javascript. I have font folder under assets folder in project and use `@font-face` in css file for applying font.`(My font is persian)`

When the section of design of project `(html,css,js)` run in browser is true and fonts apply.

When project android compile this fonts don't apply for text but apply for numbers.

Please help me.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344080/how-to-use-custom-font-with-webview

Answer (score 0):

Add your `font.ttf` in `assets` folder of your android application.

Then, For Example,

**CODE**

```
wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
String st = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">@font-face {font-family:MyFont;src: url(\"file:///android_asset/font/font.ttf\")}body {font-family:MyFont;font-size: medium;text-align: justify;}</style></head><body>";
String ed = "</body></html>";
String myHtmlString = st + YourText + ed;
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,myHtmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: I don't have any component android (textview , ...). I use webview.

Comment: I have html file and css file in assets folder.How I use loadDataWithBaseURL?

Comment: @MostafaHassani : I have got the solution for this.If you have not found the answer yet, do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Put your fonts in directory called "fonts" under your PhoneGap www folder.

Using CSS include your fonts like this (I have used Roboto Fonts here in this example):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Roboto Condensed Regular'), local('RobotoCondensed-Regular'), url(../fonts/RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

Wherever you want to apply Roboto fonts, apply like this in css: i.e.

```
font: 400 1.25em/45px 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
```

Note that, For Android Version greater than 4 it can Use bundled Fonts.
However for Android Version < 4 need to download fonts From Web like this:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Hope this helps..