# Does anybody know how to justify a textview content in a ANDROID layout?

Tags: android, textview, justify

I have been playing with android:gravity attribut but still cannot make my text content justify in the textview. Does anybody know if it is supported ? Is there a way ? Anybody succeeded ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android TextView Justify Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text)

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that Android does not support full Justification. :(

The best you can achieve is Left or Right Justification.

[Android TextView Justify Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text)

Answer (score 0):

You could also make the width of the TextView to wrap its content ("wrap_content") and justify the TextView in its parent Layout.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code:

```
        public class TextJustify {

        final static String SYSTEM_NEWLINE = "\n";
        final static float COMPLEXITY = 5.12f; // Reducing this will increase
                                     // efficiency but will decrease
                                    // effectiveness
        final static Paint p = new Paint();

        /* @author Mathew Kurian */

   public static void run(final TextView tv, float origWidth, 
          int paddingLeft, int   paddingRight, int marginLeft, int marginRight) {


    origWidth-= paddingRight+marginRight+paddingLeft+marginLeft;
    String s = tv.getText().toString();
    p.setTypeface(tv.getTypeface());
    String[] splits = s.split(SYSTEM_NEWLINE);
    float width = origWidth - 5;
    for (int x = 0; x < splits.length; x++)
        if (p.measureText(splits[x]) > width) {
            splits[x] = wrap(splits[x], width, p);
            String[] microSplits = splits[x].split(SYSTEM_NEWLINE);
            for (int y = 0; y < microSplits.length - 1; y++)
                microSplits[y] = justify(removeLast(microSplits[y], " "),
                        width, p);
            StringBuilder smb_internal = new StringBuilder();
            for (int z = 0; z < microSplits.length; z++)
                smb_internal.append(microSplits[z]
                        + ((z + 1 < microSplits.length) ? SYSTEM_NEWLINE
                                : ""));
            splits[x] = smb_internal.toString();
        }
    final StringBuilder smb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String cleaned : splits)
        smb.append(cleaned + SYSTEM_NEWLINE);
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    tv.setText(smb);
    }

   private static String wrap(String s, float width, Paint p) {

   String[] str = s.split("\\s"); // regex
    StringBuilder smb = new StringBuilder(); // save memory
    smb.append(SYSTEM_NEWLINE);
    for (int x = 0; x < str.length; x++) {
        float length = p.measureText(str[x]);
        String[] pieces = smb.toString().split(SYSTEM_NEWLINE);
        try {
            if (p.measureText(pieces[pieces.length - 1]) + length > width)
                smb.append(SYSTEM_NEWLINE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        smb.append(str[x] + " ");
    }
    return smb.toString().replaceFirst(SYSTEM_NEWLINE, "");
  }

private static String removeLast(String s, String g) {
       if (s.contains(g)) {
           int index = s.lastIndexOf(g);
           int indexEnd = index + g.length();
           if (index == 0)
               return s.substring(1);
          else if (index == s.length() - 1)
               return s.substring(0, index);
          else
              return s.substring(0, index) + s.substring(indexEnd);
    }
    return s;
}

private static String justifyOperation(String s, float width, Paint p) {
    float holder = (float) (COMPLEXITY * Math.random());
    while (s.contains(Float.toString(holder)))
        holder = (float) (COMPLEXITY * Math.random());
        String holder_string = Float.toString(holder);
    float lessThan = width;
    int timeOut = 100;
    int current = 0;
    while (p.measureText(s) < lessThan && current < timeOut) {
        s = s.replaceFirst(" ([^" + holder_string + "])", " "
                + holder_string + "$1");
            lessThan = p.measureText(holder_string) + lessThan
                - p.measureText(" ");
        current++;
    }
    String cleaned = s.replaceAll(holder_string, " ");
    return cleaned;
}

private static String justify(String s, float width, Paint p) {
    while (p.measureText(s) < width) {
        s = justifyOperation(s, width, p);
    }
return s;
}
  }
```

and for calling this I create formula, you must use following code:

```
 public static final int FinallwidthDp  = 320 ;
 public static final int widthJustify  = 223 ;

 DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
 getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
 int widthPixels = metrics.widthPixels;

 float scaleFactor = metrics.density;
 float widthDp = widthPixels / scaleFactor;

 TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
 ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lp1 = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) tv.getLayoutParams();

 tv.setText(text);
 TextJustify.run(tv,widthDp / FinallwidthDp * widthJustify , tv.getPaddingLeft(),tv.getPaddingRight() , lp1.leftMargin, lp1.rightMargin);
```

this algorithm tested on various device and worked fine in normal activity (not dialog) and `wrap-content` width for `TextView`, and worked with every padding and margin.if not good for you, you can change `widthJustify` until look good to you, I hope this useful

Answer (score -1):

XML Layout: declare WebView instead of TextView

```
<WebView
 android:id="@+id/textContent"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Java code: set text data to WebView

```
WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.textContent);
String text;
text = "<html><body><p align=\"justify\">";
text+= "This is the text will be justified when displayed!!!";
text+= "</p></body></html>";
view.loadData(text, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

This may Solve your problem.