# Android right-left justification of view element in layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

How do you get a view to position itself left, right and center in a TableLayout row? Or linear layout?

Comment: Refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text/2899082#2899082)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *android:gravity* property to set the alignment you want.

```
<TableRow android:gravity="center">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center">
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
```

When working on the TableLayout, look for the streachColoum property. Also make it * if you want all the table columns to auto fit.

Comment: Is the name actually *"streachColoum"*? For instance, *"Coloum"* is close to *"[Column](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/column#Noun)"*.