# Android TextView Justify Align

Tags: android, textview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android TextView Justify Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text)

What would be the best way to go about implementing justification in android's textviews. I know it's not built-in, but I'm wondering how I could add it.