# Can I set property of Textview like justify?

Tags: android

I want to set TextView property like right align, left align, of justify

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android TextView Justify Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, you can't set the property like gravity. But still you can set the justification to your text by taking webview instead of text view.

You may refer to [this](http://www.seal.io/2010/12/only-way-how-to-align-text-in-block-in.html).

Comment: Link is dead (2020)

Answer (score 11):

What I understand from your question is, you want to know, how to set the alignment of text inside a TextView. You can align text in TextView to left, right, or center.

To do it from your layout (XML) file, use the following attribute in your layout file;

```
android:gravity=alignment
```

*where,*

alignment can be

- left to align text to left
- right to align text to right
- center to center the text

To do the same from code, use the following;

```
TextView textRegion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textRegion);
textRegion.setGravity(gravity);
```

*where,*

gravity =

```
Gravity.LEFT to align to left
Gravity.RIGHT to align to right
Gravity.CENTER to center the text
```

Note that, justify is not available yet for text alignment in TextView.

**Update as of Android 8 (Oreo, [API Level](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels) 26):**
Justification is now possible but look quite jagged at right end.
See [setJustificationMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setJustificationMode(int))

Answer (score 4):

look at the following code..

```
<TextView style="@style/TitleBarText1" android:text="@string/app_name" />
```

Style is defined below.. here  most of the field may not necessary but helpfull .. see the **gravity** attribute and you can align the textview with this attribute...
[image]

```
 <style name="TitleBarText1">
    <item name="android:id">@id/title_text</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_medium</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">12dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">12dip</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/title_text</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
  </style>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

It's called gravity.

On XML:

android:gravity="left" or "right"

Justify is not available.

Check: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html

Answer (score 2):

To align the text

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_intro"
        style="@style/light_brown_bold_important"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_welcome"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="@string/intro"
        android:gravity="center" />
```

The important part is the

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`TextView.setGravity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setGravity(int)). For example, use `Gravity.RIGHT` for right-aligned text and `Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL` to center it. Justified text is not currently supported.

If you need more sophisticated layout control of text (for display only), use a `WebView`.

Answer (score 0):

Use **RelativeLayout** as the parent layout for textView
and use the xml proeprties of TextView like:

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

other prpertioes are also avialble to set the alignment and postion.

This [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html) may help you too.

Answer (score 0):

Example : For left justification  add this to your TextView

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
```