# Align data in Justified format by using TextView in android.

Tags: android, textview, text-alignment

I have one layout it contains data which will display to user when he press textview.In that lay out it contain lot of data that's way i use one string resource file to display that data and by using setResource i will access that file when ever i want.Everything is fine it display the data but alignment of data is not good.I want data will display in the format of Justified.

**Note** -I already try the WebView ,it is working but it don't take resource file and i want use the textview only.

Following is the code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_textview"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    /></LinearLayout>

TextView textviewTitle = (TextView) viewActionBar.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_textview);
            textviewTitle.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.terms_services_title));
```

This `R.string.terms_services_title` file contain data.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text

Comment: use this link:https://github.com/ufo22940268/android-justifiedtextview

Comment: @Shaishav i already try all suggestions in that question but those are not work for my situation i want use Textview only.

Comment: Those are used Webview.

Comment: Justify format of text view is only possible by Web view there is not option in textview for justify format.

Comment: @Aditi then how can i access string file from resources i try by using webview but it is not happen.Do you have any idea about it i am new to android.

Comment: Refer the below code it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer Here**

[Can I set property of Textview like justify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976627/can-i-set-property-of-textview-like-justify)

No, you can't set justify textview in android. But you can set the justification to your text by taking webview instead of text view.

You may refer to [this](http://www.seal.io/2010/12/only-way-how-to-align-text-in-block-in.html).

**Code**

```
import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.webkit.WebView;

 public class Main extends Activity {

    WebView mWebView;

    @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);    

       String text = "<html><body>"
        + "<p align=\"justify\">"                
           + getString(R.string.terms_services_title) 
         + "</p> "
         + "</body></html>";

     mWebView.loadData(text, "text/html", "utf-8");
     }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <WebView
       android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: by using that we can align data but i have one string resource file,i am using that file to display data i am not directly write strings in layout file.It contain 20 strings.

Comment: You not need to in take in layout..... See the Answer  String text = "<html><body>"
        + "<p align=\"justify\">"                
           + getString(R.string.terms_services_title) 
         + "</p> "
         + "</body></html>";

Comment: or by this... on code getResources().getString(R.string.terms_services_title)

Comment: yes @Arjun is right if you have such issue then you can refer his idea.

Comment: yes i try this but it is not working for file.Like if you give any one string it will work.i want align what ever data placed in one file.

Comment: i try for load url it will get file but can't align.

Comment: Which file .txt or .pdf??

Answer (score 0):

try the below one:-

Inside strings file put your string in html form

```
<string name="web_text">
<![CDATA[
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body style="text-align:justify;color:gray;background-color:black;">
  Your text here!!
 </body>
</html>
]]>
</string>
```

and use inside Java file like this

```
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
setContentView(R.layout.web_layout);
 WebView view = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    view.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    view.loadData(getString(R.string.web_text), "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");
}
```

and inside web_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It will work for one string but i have 20 strings and some strings have styles.