# Right align text in android TextView

Tags: android, alignment, textview

I have a `TextView` in my application. I want to align the text in it to the right. I tried adding:

```
android:gravity="right"
```

But this doesn't work for me.

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 206, accepted):

I think that you are doing this: `android:layout_width = "wrap_content"`
If this is the case, do this: `android:layout_width = "match_parent"`

Comment: @Bishan fill will fill the remainder of the space, match will set it equal to the width of the parent

Comment: Actually, fill_parent and match_parent are the same thing. The name was changed to match_parent because apparently fill_parent was confusing people.

Comment: This answer doesn't make sence...

Answer (score 171):

In general, `android:gravity="right"` is different from `android:layout_gravity="right"`.

The first one affects the position of the text itself within the View, so if you want it to be right-aligned, then `layout_width=` should be either `"fill_parent"` or `"match_parent"`.

The second one affects the View's position inside its parent, in other words - aligning the object itself (edit box or text view) inside the parent view.

Answer (score 102):

**The better solution is the one that is the most simple, and the one that does less modification in your code behaviour**.

What if you can solve this problem only with 2 Properties on your `TextView`?

Instead of needing to change your `LinearLayout` Properties that maybe can alter the behaviour of `LinearLayout` childs?

Using this way, you do not need to change `LinearLayout` properties and behaviour, you only need to add the two following properties to your target `TextView`:

```
android:gravity="right"
android:textAlignment="gravity"
```

What would be better to change only your target to solve your solution instead of having a chance to cause another problem in the future, modifying your target father? think about it :)

Comment: I get an error saying no resource identifier found for resource 'textAlignment' in package android.

Comment: You have sure that you are acessing a `TextView` properties? - You can check the property from the reference here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:textAlignment

Comment: textAlignment was added in API level 17 (Android 4.2).
Your emulator/device will need to be running 4.2+ for this to work.

Comment: I have tried to use this textAlignment property in Android 4.1.2 and got the error "No resource identifier found for attribute 'textAlignment'". I found the answer for this error here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20176191/723507. How could you use it in 4.0.3?

Answer (score 22):

In case somebody still needs

```
android:gravity="end"
```

Comment: what's that for?

Comment: In LTR, this aligns the text to right and in RTL, to the left

Answer (score 21):

`android:layout_gravity` is used to align the text view with respect to the parent layout.
`android:gravity` is used to align the text inside the text view.

Are you sure you are trying to align the text inside the text view to the right or do you want to move the text view itself to the right with respect to the parent layout or are you trying to acheive both

Comment: i'm trying to align the text inside the text view to the right

Answer (score 15):

The following code snippet:

```
android:textAlignment="textEnd"
android:layout_gravity="end"
```

works great for me

Answer (score 9):

```
android:gravity="right"
```

It is basically used in Linear Layout so you have to set your width of TextView or either EditText as

```
android:layout_width = "match_parent"
```

and

When you are working in Relative Layout, use

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

Answer (score 8):

Make sure that you are not using `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` if so then it won't be able to set the gravity because you are not having enough space for the text to align. Instead use `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`

Answer (score 5):

If it is in `RelativeLayout` you can use `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/<id_of_desired_item>"`

**Or**

If you want to align to the `right` corner of the device the place `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`

Answer (score 5):

Make the (LinearLayout) `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and the TextView's `android:layout_gravity="right"`

Answer (score 5):

Below works for me:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_username"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sarah" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_distance"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_username"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_username"
    android:text="San Marco"
    android:textAlignment="viewEnd" />
```

Please note the `android:layout_alignParentEnd` and `android:textAlignment` settings of the second TextView.

Answer (score 4):

> Let me explain gravity concept using **WEB** because a lot of developer are aware of it.

`android_layout_gravity` behaves `float:left|right|top|bottom`

Whereas `android_gravity` work as `text_align:centre|left|right`

In Android float is android_layout_gravity and text_align: is android_gravity.

**And android_layout_gravity applies relative to parent. where as android_gravity applies to its child or inner content.**

**Note** android_gravity only works when its View is match_parent(when it have space to center).

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

Answer (score 2):

this should serve the purpose

`android:textAlignment="textStart"`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was using `Relative Layout` for a `emptyString`

After struggling on this for an hour. Only this worked for me:

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/welcome"
android:layout_toEndOf="@id/welcome"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/welcome"
```

`layout_toRightOf` or `layout_toEndOf` both works, but to support it better, I used both.

**To make it more clear:**

This was what I was trying to do:

[image]

And this was the emulator's output

[image]

**Layout:**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/welcome"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Welcome "
    android:textSize="16sp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/welcome"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/welcome"
    android:text="@string/emptyString"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

**Notice that:**

1. `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` works
2. `Gravity` is not used

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem and figured the problem was happening as the layout_width of the TextView was having wrap_content. You need to have layout_width as match_parent and the android:gravity = "gravity"

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tct_postpone_hour"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="1"
    android:textSize="24dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

makes number one align in center both horizontal and vertical.

Answer (score 1):

Try using :-

```
android:justificationMode="inter_word"
```

this will justify your text.

Answer (score 0):

try to add `android:gravity="center"` into `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

I have used the attribute "layout_alignRight" in my case, in text its :

```
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/myComponentId"
```

If you want to add some right margin, just set the attribute "Layout_Margin Right" to "20dp" for exemple, in text its :

```
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Justification Alignment has been supported for TextView from Android API 26+

```
<TextView ...
    ... android:justificationMode="inter_word" />
```

By default, value is none.

[image: Android TextView JustificationMode none vs inter_word]

[Android TextView Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:justificationMode)

[Question on Android TextView Justify Text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42991773/115145)