# How to align the text inside the TextView in Android?

Tags: android, textview, android-gui

I have a multiline TextView in Android. It is a child of a LinearLayout. It is already centered horizontally and I also want to have the text inside it centered.

**Here's what I have now:**

```
_ _ _ _ _ _| aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  
_ _ _ _ _ _| aaaaaaaa  
_ _ _ _ _ _| aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

**What I want is:**

```
_ _ _ _ _ _| aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  
_ _ _ _ _ _|       aaaaaaaa  
_ _ _ _ _ _|     aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

**Where:**

_ _ _ _ = the space on the side of the TextView

| = the TextView edge

Comment: See detail explanation of gravity http://stackoverflow.com/a/36981904/3496570

Comment: Use `android:textAlignment="center"` see the detail solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56453101/2380114

Comment: Why do I feel that @Chathura Wijesinghe answered the real question? Got my upvote!

Comment: unfortunately, it was deleted by @bhargav-rao .  the same solution I used for most off the apps.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Did you try the `gravity` attribute on the `TextView` ?

```
  android:gravity="center"
```

And make sure to use `android:gravity` and not `android:layout_gravity`.

Comment: Make sure to use android:gravity and not android:layout_gravity. This just cost me 30 min.

Comment: Thank you very much @AlexanderPacha This should be added to the answer as I also got confused

Comment: Miraculous! I wonder what the heck android:textAlignment is supposed to do? But not enough to actually dig for it. This works!

Answer (score 15):

`android:gravity="center_horizontal"` should do the trick.

More information could be found [here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/14/how-to-position-views-properly-in-layouts/) or [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:gravity).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use **android:gravity** attribute to change the position of data inside views.

Answer (score 3):

The gravity attribute is the update to Alignment. Gravity is available in the attributes inspector as well as being able to do;

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to align your text in textView then `textAlignment` is better option then gravity.

Add `android:textAlignment="center"` for `Center`

Add `android:textAlignment="textStart"` for `Left`

Add `android:textAlignment="textEnd"` for `Right`

Answer (score -1):

Make the text (which you want to set into TextView) in strings.xml as following :

```
<string name="content">
<center>Your text goes here.</center>
</string>
```

and in TextView add following attribute:

```
<TextView
...
android:text="@string/content"/>
```

It will center the text into TextView horizontally.