# Align text right in Android textview

Tags: android, textview, alignment

I am trying to align text in `textview` to right side. I have added `android:gravity="right"` to textview properties, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the full xml of your `TextView` and possibly an image of how it looks now? That is how you would do it but you must have something else going on.

Comment: Post some relevant code of your xml ! i think your `TextView` has `android:layout_width = "wrap_content"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Right align text in android TextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969122/right-align-text-in-android-textview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please DO search before asking questions.
You probably need to check your `android:layout_width` property, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969122/right-align-text-in-android-textview).

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change `android:layout_width = "wrap_content"` to `android:layout_width = "fill_parent"`