# error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'textAlignment' in package 'android'

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

This is my res/layout mobile.xml file. Where is my mistake? When I run textview has this error.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp" >
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="118dp"
    android:src="@drawable/android_logo" >
    </ImageView>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textAlignment="center" >
    </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 49):

`textAlignment` was added in API level 17 (Android 4.2).

Your emulator/device will need to be running 4.2+ for this to work.

Otherwise just use `android:gravity="center"`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what problem could be in this line:

```
android:text="@+id/label"
```

try this:

```
android:text="@string/label"
```