# getting error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'textAlignment' in package 'android'

Tags: android, xml

Hello I keep getting this error in my  xml: "error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'textAlignment' in package 'android'"

I have tried googleing the error but no luck heres my xml code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFe5e5e5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!--     <EditText -->
    <!--         android:id="@+id/txtItem" -->
    <!--         android:layout_width="fill_parent" -->
    <!--         android:layout_height="wrap_content" -->
    <!--         android:inputType="text" > -->

    <!--         <requestFocus /> -->
    <!--     </EditText> -->

    <!--     <Button -->
    <!--         android:id="@+id/btnAdd" -->
    <!--         android:layout_width="fill_parent" -->
    <!--         android:layout_height="wrap_content" -->
    <!--         android:text="@string/add" /> -->

Error is flagging here: <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCurrentListName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/reminder_bg"
            android:text="default"
            android:textColor="#FFffffff"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="28sp"
             />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listCurrentListItems"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

any help would be amazing

Thanks way in advance

Regards

Chris

Comment: You might use `android:gravity` instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`android:textAlignment` was added in API Level 17](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3atextAlignment). Make sure that your build target (e.g., Project > Properties > Android in Eclipse) is set to 17 or higher.

Comment: An additional information: For older platforms you can use the android:gravity attribute. See here for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20176191/2253407 It is available since API Level 1