# android-TextView setGravity doesn't working

Tags: android

I have a problem.I'm trying to create TextView with specification dimensions, and i do it in onMeasure method.My progblem is i want to change the textalignment, so i call setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT) method but it's not working, the text is still in left side.

Below is my code, i hope someone'll help me :(

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    MyLabel label = new MyLabel(this);
    label.setText("Hello");
    label.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    label.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    layout.addView(label);

    setContentView(layout);

}

public class MyLabel extends TextView {

    public MyLabel(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        // Desire Size : Mac dinh la Wrap Content
        float desireWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
        float desireHeight = getMeasuredHeight();

        int maxWidth = 0;
        int maxHeight = 0;
        float width = 0.7f;
        float height = 0.3f;

        if (maxWidth == 0) {
            maxWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        }

        if (maxHeight == 0) {
            maxHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        }

        // Neu abstract model co thong tin ve kich thuoc :
        if (width > 0) {

            int parentWidth = 0;
            if (true) {
                parentWidth = maxWidth;
            } else {
                parentWidth = 480;
            }
            if (width <= 1) {
                // Gia tri duoc tinh toan theo % cua parent
                desireWidth = width * parentWidth;
            } else {
                desireWidth = width < parentWidth ? width : parentWidth;
            }
        }

        // Kich thuoc chieu cao cung tuong tu nhu vay
        if (height > 0) {

            int parentHeight = 0;
            if (true) {
                parentHeight = maxHeight;
            } else {
                parentHeight = 800;
            }
            if (height <= 1) {
                // Gia tri duoc tinh toan theo % cua parent
                desireHeight = height * parentHeight;
            } else {
                desireHeight = height < parentHeight ? height
                        : parentHeight;
            }
        }
        // Cuoi cung, ta set kich thuoc cho view
        this.setMeasuredDimension((int) desireWidth, (int) desireHeight);
    }
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Right align text in android TextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969122/right-align-text-in-android-textview)

Comment: Not a duplicate, that question deals with static xml layouts not dynamic code generated ones.

Comment: I think its not problem with ur gravity. Just set a size to your layout like match_parent.den see whether ur text z at right or not.

Answer (score 2):

Making layouts in Java can be useful, but sometimes important implementation details are hidden from you when you do. This is one of those times.

When you call `addView()`, the view being added gets a default LayoutParams object from the parent view. In the case of LinearLayout, this default LayoutParams object has the width and height specified as `WRAP_CONTENT`. Since your TextView is only as large as its content, changing its gravity has no apparent effect.

You need to create a LayoutParams object and provide it to `addView()`. You can set its gravity to `RIGHT` or you can use `MATCH_PARENT` for its width.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
linearLayout.addView(textView, params);
```

Note that LinearLayout by default has `HORIZONTAL` orientation, which tends not to be so useful when it's the root of a screen layout. You might want to call `linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL)` on it.

Comment: I know, but i must use onMeasure(), because i want to set the TextView size by the percentage of parent's size.LayoutParams has WEIGHT property, but it just change width(with HORIZONTAL) or height(with VERTICAL)