# Align views to the right in ScrollView

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I have a HorizontalScrollView and inside a TextView. I want the text of the TextView always aligned to the right. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want the views to be aligned to the right or the text inside the `TextView`?

Comment: Show your codes, images etc. Explain what you want clearly. Your question is not clear.

Comment: This might solve your problem: <https://stackoverflow.com/a/8969168/7656601>

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code in your textView `android:textAlignment="viewEnd"`