# How to align text in TextView when the TextView is match constraint?

Tags: android, textview, alignment

How to align text in TextView when it is match_constraint.

I tried 
`android:layout_gravity="right"`

 and

```
android:gravity="right"
```

but none of these works.

is there a way to achieve horizontal aligment of text in match_constraint?

Seems like a simple task but im looking for a solution for a days....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Right align text in android TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969122/right-align-text-in-android-textview)

Answer (score 1):

```
android:gravity="right"
```

This will work to align text in your textview. if its not working there is some other issue with your code. Post your code if you need more help