# How to align text in Android Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am new to android development.

Text Align Problems :

- I am able to center, left or right align the text.

How can I `justify` text in android?

Comment: fill_parent property may help you.

Comment: Full Justification is not possible. Check out this work around http://stackoverflow.com/a/4314724/28557

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android TextView Justify Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vinayak.B's suggestion is an excellent workaround. http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/4314724/28557

Answer (score 1):

Android does not support full justification of the text. The alignments you list are the only ones available.

Your best option would be to load the text into a webview and use CSS to justify it.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Justify Alignment is not possible in Android Layout.

Answer (score 0):

http://sealskej.blogspot.in/2010/12/only-way-how-to-align-text-in-block-in.html

I found this good workaround using webview.

if anyone figures out something better than this - do let me know.