# How to align text on both left and right side of one TextView line?

Tags: android, textview, alignment, spannablestring

I want to set text in a single line TextView on both left and right side of the only line.
For this I use a SpannableStringBuilder.

Here is an example :

```
mSpannableStringBuilder.append("leftright");
mSpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL), 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
mSpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE), 4, 8, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
mTextView.setText(mSpannableStringBuilder, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

But it doesn't work ...
Any suggestions please ?
Thanks you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android TextView Justify Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a certain part of a android-textview align to the right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520808/make-a-certain-part-of-a-android-textview-align-to-the-right)

Comment: Working solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/36488501/2970351

Answer (score 0):

I just use in the xml file as the below

`<RelativeLayout
             android:orientation="horizontal"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:gravity="center_horizontal"
             >
                <TextView 
                    android:text="AAA:"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#3b5998"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    />
                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/maine"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Not Set"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#0040FF" 
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

                    />
             </RelativeLayout>`

Answer (score 0):

Check if your xml tag contains "android:textAlignment" or "android:gravity" properties. In positive case, remove it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with the span, but requires a linefeed between the left and right string which sort of sucks. If there is no linefeed, it can only align the line left or right, but not split as left and right.