# Android Textview setText inner Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I want to settext like this

```
String Result = "Customer Name :"+getSpace()+CustomerName+System.getProperty ("line.separator")+
    "Customer Age :"+getSpace()+CustomerAge+System.getProperty ("line.separator")+
    "Money  :"+getSpace()+CustomerMoney+System.getProperty ("line.separator");
        ExampleTextView.setText(Result );
```

Function Code

```
public String getSpace(){

 String Space="";
 for(int i=0;i<getSpaceCount();i++)
 {
  Space+=" ";
 }

}
```

After than i want to result Like this
| <- is Layout border

```
|Customer Name :        Akshan Ormani To|
|Customer Age :                       19| 
|Money :                           20.0€|
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use `AlignmentSpan.Standard` for this. I'm not sure though, didn't try it myself.

[See here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520808/make-a-certain-part-of-a-android-textview-align-to-the-right)