# Android Studio TextView format one String center

Tags: android, format

Hello I got two Strings and a TextView:

```
TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eins);
String one = "DynamicText";
String two = "Title";
test.setText(two+one);
```

Now I would to set the two Strings in **one** TextView but I like to formate the String two text align to center and the String one normal (left). How is this possible?

Comment: The easiest way is to create two `TextView`s

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/14520808/4854891

Comment: use SpannableString or two TextViews to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView txtOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtOne );
TextView txtTwo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtOne);
textOne.setText("DynamicText");
txtTwo.setText("Title");
txtTwo.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```