# Justifying text in Android

Tags: java, android, textview, text-justify

I need to justify some text (RTL), which is a string (`S1`) from the server. But a `TextView` can't justify text, so I have to use a `WebView`, now I have to create a HTML file in which
will display `S1`. And then I store the address of that html file in the database and then I display that html file. I've seen this question asked before on SO and many have recommended to use a 3rd party library, I've tried all of those approaches to no avail (they work in 90% of scenarios but are no fully reliable).

I feel that this approach seems convoluted, I was wondering if there is a better approach?

Comment: can you give some sample. How do you want to justify?.. check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2899082/2219600).

Comment: i want justify Persian text, and if I cant justify with some class or library i should get String and Create HTML file and load into WebView.

Comment: Here is exactly what you are looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4314724/2219600

Comment: @amalBit your first link does is align text left or right. This doesn't justify the text and second link is what i must do, but this is static and i must create many html file into database

Comment: Well thats the best android can do for justification.

Comment: I have updated https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android with the latest technique. This should be loads better now. @amalBit There is a work around!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android TextView Justify Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text)

Comment: @blahdiblah really? did you read my question? i needed one approach for that solution, I mentioned in my question that this question asked before, any way, you have right to close question and down vote, but after that read questions with more time. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the following code that answer with very people that need this subject and i create formula that support in every display.

```
    public class TextJustify {

final static String SYSTEM_NEWLINE = "\n";
final static float COMPLEXITY = 5.12f; // Reducing this will increase
                                        // efficiency but will decrease
                                        // effectiveness
final static Paint p = new Paint();

/* @author Mathew Kurian */

public static void run(final TextView tv, float origWidth, int paddingLeft, int paddingRight, int marginLeft, int marginRight) {


    origWidth-= paddingRight+marginRight+paddingLeft+marginLeft;
    String s = tv.getText().toString();
    p.setTypeface(tv.getTypeface());
    String[] splits = s.split(SYSTEM_NEWLINE);
    float width = origWidth - 5;
    for (int x = 0; x < splits.length; x++)
        if (p.measureText(splits[x]) > width) {
            splits[x] = wrap(splits[x], width, p);
            String[] microSplits = splits[x].split(SYSTEM_NEWLINE);
            for (int y = 0; y < microSplits.length - 1; y++)
                microSplits[y] = justify(removeLast(microSplits[y], " "),
                        width, p);
            StringBuilder smb_internal = new StringBuilder();
            for (int z = 0; z < microSplits.length; z++)
                smb_internal.append(microSplits[z]
                        + ((z + 1 < microSplits.length) ? SYSTEM_NEWLINE
                                : ""));
            splits[x] = smb_internal.toString();
        }
    final StringBuilder smb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String cleaned : splits)
        smb.append(cleaned + SYSTEM_NEWLINE);
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    tv.setText(smb);
}

private static String wrap(String s, float width, Paint p) {
    String[] str = s.split("\\s"); // regex
    StringBuilder smb = new StringBuilder(); // save memory
    smb.append(SYSTEM_NEWLINE);
    for (int x = 0; x < str.length; x++) {
        float length = p.measureText(str[x]);
        String[] pieces = smb.toString().split(SYSTEM_NEWLINE);
        try {
            if (p.measureText(pieces[pieces.length - 1]) + length > width)
                smb.append(SYSTEM_NEWLINE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        smb.append(str[x] + " ");
    }
    return smb.toString().replaceFirst(SYSTEM_NEWLINE, "");
}

private static String removeLast(String s, String g) {
    if (s.contains(g)) {
        int index = s.lastIndexOf(g);
        int indexEnd = index + g.length();
        if (index == 0)
            return s.substring(1);
        else if (index == s.length() - 1)
            return s.substring(0, index);
        else
            return s.substring(0, index) + s.substring(indexEnd);
    }
    return s;
}

private static String justifyOperation(String s, float width, Paint p) {
    float holder = (float) (COMPLEXITY * Math.random());
    while (s.contains(Float.toString(holder)))
        holder = (float) (COMPLEXITY * Math.random());
    String holder_string = Float.toString(holder);
    float lessThan = width;
    int timeOut = 100;
    int current = 0;
    while (p.measureText(s) < lessThan && current < timeOut) {
        s = s.replaceFirst(" ([^" + holder_string + "])", " "
                + holder_string + "$1");
        lessThan = p.measureText(holder_string) + lessThan
                - p.measureText(" ");
        current++;
    }
    String cleaned = s.replaceAll(holder_string, " ");
    return cleaned;
}

private static String justify(String s, float width, Paint p) {
    while (p.measureText(s) < width) {
        s = justifyOperation(s, width, p);
    }
    return s;
}
  }
```

and for calling this you mus use following code, I tested for Persian language and in every display and device worked fine.

```
     public static final int FinallwidthDp  = 320 ;
     public static final int widthJustify  = 223 ;

     DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
     getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
     int widthPixels = metrics.widthPixels;

     float scaleFactor = metrics.density;
     float widthDp = widthPixels / scaleFactor;

     TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lp1 = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) tv.getLayoutParams();

     tv.setText(text);
     TextJustify.run(tv,widthDp / FinallwidthDp * widthJustify , tv.getPaddingLeft(),tv.getPaddingRight() , lp1.leftMargin, lp1.rightMargin);
```

this algorithm tested on various device and worked fine in normal activity (not dialog) and `wrap-content` width for `TextView`, and worked with every padding and margin.if not good for you, you can change `widthJustify` until look good to you, I hope this useful.
for newly update see [This](https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android)

Comment: Hello, I am the one who had written this library. I would be obliged if you can add support for all calculating the `widthDp` for all devices. I don't have an Android device so it would be hard for me to code and test. To add this support, please fork this https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android, make your changes and then do a pull request and I will merge in the code. I will also add you as a contributor as well. Thank you very much.

Comment: @mk1 I edited your library but i don't know that I confirm edit or not because i never do like this, please tell me result of My Edit,
I edit two file,read me and your class, in read me i add 10 - 15 line and in your class add 2 line,

Comment: I saw your edits I have merged them. I have reopened one issue there, hopefully you can look into it.

Comment: @mk1 In some lines spacing between words is so much and not looking so good. How to solve this problem?

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan same question if you know please help me.

Comment: @JohnR did you see the link? did you used second way because that is much better performance, ( i think ). i really don't know i just brought one formula for this, all algorithm is for mk1. change value of `widthJustify` and see result, may be look better

Comment: second option is not working. So author of that project told me to use first option.

Answer (score 2):

**LIBRARY**: https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android

**SUPPORTS**: Android 2.0 to 5.X; String/Spannables; RTL language support! **NO WEBVIEW :)**

**SCREENSHOT**

[image: Comparison.png]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add a **TextViewJustify.java** file in src folder.

**TextViewJustify.java** wil be like this

```
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TextViewJustify {

    /*
     * PLEASE DO NOT REMOVE Coded by Mathew Kurian I wrote this code for a
     * Google Interview for Internship. Unfortunately, I got too nervous during
     * the interview that I messed, but anyhow that doesn't matter. I have
     * resent my work in hopes that I might still get a position there. Thank
     * you :DD
     */

    final static String SYSTEM_NEWLINE = "\n";
    final static float COMPLEXITY = 5.12f; // Reducing this will increase
                                            // efficiency but will decrease
                                            // effectiveness
    final static Paint p = new Paint();

    public static void justifyText(final TextView tv, final float origWidth) {
        String s = tv.getText().toString();
        p.setTypeface(tv.getTypeface());
        String[] splits = s.split(SYSTEM_NEWLINE);
        float width = origWidth - 5;
        for (int x = 0; x < splits.length; x++)
            if (p.measureText(splits[x]) > width) {
                splits[x] = wrap(splits[x], width, p);
                String[] microSplits = splits[x].split(SYSTEM_NEWLINE);
                for (int y = 0; y < microSplits.length - 1; y++)
                    microSplits[y] = justify(removeLast(microSplits[y], " "),
                            width, p);
                StringBuilder smb_internal = new StringBuilder();
                for (int z = 0; z < microSplits.length; z++)
                    smb_internal.append(microSplits[z]
                            + ((z + 1 < microSplits.length) ? SYSTEM_NEWLINE
                                    : ""));
                splits[x] = smb_internal.toString();
            }
        final StringBuilder smb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String cleaned : splits)
            smb.append(cleaned + SYSTEM_NEWLINE);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        tv.setText(smb);
    }

    private static String wrap(String s, float width, Paint p) {
        String[] str = s.split("\\s"); // regex
        StringBuilder smb = new StringBuilder(); // save memory
        smb.append(SYSTEM_NEWLINE);
        for (int x = 0; x < str.length; x++) {
            float length = p.measureText(str[x]);
            String[] pieces = smb.toString().split(SYSTEM_NEWLINE);
            try {
                if (p.measureText(pieces[pieces.length - 1]) + length > width)
                    smb.append(SYSTEM_NEWLINE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            smb.append(str[x] + " ");
        }
        return smb.toString().replaceFirst(SYSTEM_NEWLINE, "");
    }

    private static String removeLast(String s, String g) {
        if (s.contains(g)) {
            int index = s.lastIndexOf(g);
            int indexEnd = index + g.length();
            if (index == 0)
                return s.substring(1);
            else if (index == s.length() - 1)
                return s.substring(0, index);
            else
                return s.substring(0, index) + s.substring(indexEnd);
        }
        return s;
    }

    private static String justifyOperation(String s, float width, Paint p) {
        float holder = (float) (COMPLEXITY * Math.random());
        while (s.contains(Float.toString(holder)))
            holder = (float) (COMPLEXITY * Math.random());
        String holder_string = Float.toString(holder);
        float lessThan = width;
        int timeOut = 100;
        int current = 0;
        while (p.measureText(s) < lessThan && current < timeOut) {
            s = s.replaceFirst(" ([^" + holder_string + "])", " "
                    + holder_string + "$1");
            lessThan = p.measureText(holder_string) + lessThan
                    - p.measureText(" ");
            current++;
        }
        String cleaned = s.replaceAll(holder_string, " ");
        return cleaned;
    }

    private static String justify(String s, float width, Paint p) {
        while (p.measureText(s) < width) {
            s = justifyOperation(s, width, p);
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

And use this class like this:

```
TextViewJustify.justifyText(your_text_view, 225f);
```

In my case it was 225f. change it according to your need.

Comment: i use this class but this work in 90% of scenarios but are no fully reliable

Comment: This is because you cant justify text from XML.

Comment: and for your number (225f) you must set width of screen that on every screen work good, if you set final number in other dp screen is not work good

Comment: No I didn't set any width. And I used it in a dialog screen. It was working like a charm in every device. @Shayan

Comment: @Andru I didn't think people would actually use this. So I will optimize this and increase its reliability. If you are user of this, please follow its repository on github so you can stay on top of the latest releases.

Answer (score 0):

You can justify Text  using WebView Simply

```
LinearLayout lv=(LinearLayout)dialog.findViewById(R.id.**yourId**);


                     String text1 = "<html><body>"
                                + "<p align=\"justify\">"                
                                   +**your text**
                                + "</p> "
                                + "</body></html>";



                     WebView wv=new WebView(getApplicationContext());
                     wv.loadData(text1,"text/html","utf-8");



                    lv.removeAllViews();

                    lv.addView(wv);
```

Comment: yes you right but in that project i didn't want to use html file because i had many many text in database, but thanks for your solution.

Comment: if you can split your text and print it in different text views, You can use html tags for text color, text size, text style etc

Comment: I need that for law book, 100 pages and many lines, this solution is not worked for that situation. any way, problem has been solved with my answer on this post

Answer (score 0):

i made simple class.
this can be used just like TextView

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * text justifying
 * you can just use like TextView
 * @author hyunsikkim
 *
 */
public class JustifiedTextView extends TextView {

public JustifiedTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public JustifiedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

private void setBreakText(String text) {
    if(text == null) return;

    String breakText = breakText(getPaint(), text, 
            getWidth()-this.getPaddingLeft()-this.getPaddingRight());

    if(breakText.equals(getText()) == false) {
        setText(breakText);
    }
}

public String breakText(Paint textPaint, String strText, int breakWidth) { 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
    int endValue = 0; 
    final String NEW_LINE = "\n";
    do{ 
        endValue = textPaint.breakText(strText, true, breakWidth, null); 
        if(endValue > 0) {
            /**
             * handle if text contains NEW_LINE
             */
            final int index = strText.indexOf(NEW_LINE);
            if(0<=index && index <= endValue) {
                endValue = index + NEW_LINE.length();
            }
            final String sub = strText.substring(0, endValue);
            sb.append(sub);
            /**
             * handle breaked text endWidth NEW_LINE
             */
            if(sub.endsWith(NEW_LINE) == false) {
                if(strText.length() != endValue) {
                    sb.append(NEW_LINE);
                }
            }

            strText = strText.substring(endValue); 
        } 
    } while(endValue > 0);
    return sb.toString();
} 

public String breakText(Paint textPaint, int id, int breakWidth) {
    String strText = getResources().getString(id);
    return breakText(textPaint, strText, breakWidth);
}

@Override
protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start,
        int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter) {
    super.onTextChanged(text, start, lengthBefore, lengthAfter);
    /**
     * this control changes from setText(Charsequence text)
     */
    if(getWidth() != 0) {
        setBreakText(text.toString());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    /**
     * this help to break initial text.
     */
    if(w != oldw) {
        setBreakText(getText().toString());
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use web view

```
  WebView tv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.aboutme); 
  String youtContentStr = String.valueOf(Html
                        .fromHtml("<![CDATA[<body style=\"text-align:justify;background-color:#00222222;\">"
                                    + text
                                    + "</body>]]>"));

  tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
  tv.loadData(youtContentStr, "text/html", "utf-8");`
```