# Suggest me any option for using <ul> or <ol> tag for android to make justify alignment for text within strings file

Tags: android

I have string content with numbering(list items) i wanted to make justify alignment for each and every list..Please suggest me with an option for doing it..I'm populating the content from strings file into textview.

```
<string name="sample">\n Title

  \n\t1.Sub heading 1
   ggsdhsfdjshf
  \n\12.Sub heading 2
   hjdjkfhdishfidhgd
   fdgvbfhgfnn

 </string>


<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView121"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="left|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/sample"
        android:textSize="@dimen/content_text_size"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
```

For this i want the each points below sub heading to be justified..Can suggest now?

Comment: fro justify Text see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873733/justifying-text-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Html` string as the text to display in `TextView`
Try this.

```
String htmlString = "This<br>is<br>test!";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ArrayList in Android.
You can also get the the strings from string file.
You can add item using

```
ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>;
arrylist.add("1.Item1");
arrylist.add("2.Item2");
```

Comment: how this can justify text?

Comment: Can you please share some xml code which you have implement?

Comment: I don't ask this question, i just serious because OP want justify text and you answer with initialize List.