# Android - Justify alignment and custom font for Texts in Arabic and Persian languages

Tags: android, webview, textview, arabic, typography

I am developing an android application and I strongly need to use **Justify text alignment** and also I should use **custom font** for texts. my application is in **Persian** language.

If I use **TextView** for showing texts I cant set text alignment to **Justify**.

If I use **WebView** and load html to it I cant use font for it (I know that I can set font using html and css but it does not work for some languages like **Persian** and **Arabic** , I tested it, only on android **4.4.2** i see my custom font but on other versions of android webview show android **default** font)

I tried converting font to SVG but nothings changed.

also I searched in github for a custom webview or textview , I fount one custom textView , both font and text alignment was ok but the **direction** was left to right but i need it be right to left (I tried changing gravity and other things but cant fix problem).

So what is your suggestion ?
Thank you so much for helping.

Regards.

Comment: are you solved that? if yes please share with us. tnx.

Comment: @NarutoUzumaki No I didn't found any solution :'(

Comment: i need a solution too...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27729887/4905986).I used [this library](https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android) with the following attrs and everything works perfectly:

```
ext:documentView_reverse="true"
ext:documentView_textAlignment="justified"
ext:documentView_textFormat="formatted"
```