# Justify the words in TextView android

Tags: android, justify

is it possible to justify the textview field in android.

I am currently showing tamil words in my text view and the para is looking awkward can some one tell me how to justify this field

I tried different combinations of gravity and it resulted only in the alignment of the text in the left side.now the question is how can i justify the words on the right side.

i also searched and red in lots of forums that android doesnt support justification but those forums are atleast 18 months old.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1292575/827110.

Comment: Please go through the posted answers. Some of them, like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20578041/827110, solves the problem.

Comment: LIBRARY: https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android helps to do justification of the text. use this guys.