# How can I set text to justified in TextView in android?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, textview

I have already tried [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg41067.html) and other answers but not getting any solution.

Comment: Did you check this ? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text

Comment: https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android

Comment: yes, i have tried this, but this also doesn't help