# Justifying text in Android without using a WebView

Tags: android, textview

Is it possible to justify the content in Android without using a WebView?

What I have come across after searching is that Android does not support full text-justification and it can be done only through WebView. Is there any other way of doing so?

Comment: you can use static layout for text justifying.

Comment: Related: [Android TextView Justify Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text)

Answer (score 4):

### You have to use `WebView` instead of `TextView`

```
textWebview.loadData("<p style=\"text-align: justify\">"+ "  [YOUR TEXT] " +"</p>", "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

It defiantly works. 
 Thank you.

Comment: thanks for your answer @Darshak but I donot want to use WebView.

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

```
<TextView>
   ...
   android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
   ...
</TextView>
```

[Android TextView Justify Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text)

Answer (score 0):

Fully justification is not supported
You can either use multiple textview or use library

Comment: which library ? could you specify one?