# Android String HTML help needed

Tags: android, html

So in Android I wanted to justify the text so I decided to use the Webview.It works fine but the only issue I have is that the background of my app is not white. So whenever I see the text, it always has a white background. So can I add a body tag to enable it to change the background color?

```
String text = "<html><body style=\"text-align:justify\"> %s </body> </Html> ";
     // I want to include a body tag above which will make the background this color = #e6e6e6
       String data = "My Text";

       WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
       webView.loadData(String.format(text, data), "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following link.
[Android TextView Justify Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text)

It explains the justify rules in android. How to do it in webview and it also has a support library you could use to do native.

Try

```
webView.setBackgroundColor("#00000000")
```

for transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
String text = "<html><body style=\"text-align:justify; background-color:#e6e6e6;\"> %s </body></html>"
```

The `background-color` CSS property should let you set the background to whatever you want it to be.

Edit: Kalel Wade's answer is better since it's done through the Android properties as opposed to the HTML.