# textview align line ending position

Tags: android

My problem is like that, In a text view normally as many words is fitted in a line and this produce a zigzagged shape of either text or spaces. But I want the last word in each line to end on same place. And fill required spaces in a line to achieve that with spaces between words evenly. 
 
Example(normal) : 
all the words lies
My problem is like that, In a text view normally as many words is fitted in a line and this produce a zigzagged shape of either text or spaces. But I want the last word in each line to end on same place. And fill required spaces in a line to achieve that with spaces between words evenly. 
 
Example(normal):
all the words lies at
here to make 
unexpected sentence

Example(needed dots are spaces evenly divided):
all .the .words .lies .at
here....... to....... make 
unexpected sentence

Comment: You're looking for `justify` alignment of text.  Android doesn't offer this natively in TextView, but there are some workarounds.  Linked question is useful here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android TextView Justify Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text)

Comment: I really didn't know it was  called justify :) took some time trying to explain what I mean.