# Android: Justify text to the right in nested Linear Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am having a very hard time justifying TextViews to the left in Android. I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text) but did not have success. The TextViews I want to justify are in Linear Layouts nested in a parent Linear Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Button
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="@style/calibrate_button" />

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/calibrate"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            style="@style/calibrate_text" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Style:

        @color/White
        20sp
        wrap_content
        wrap_content
        ?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge
        right

```
<style name="calibrate_button">
    <item name="android:background">#fcfcfc</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Why not use RelativeLayout?

Comment: I thought that a horizontal LinearLayout would be the way to go in this situation. I have a button and textview that I want to line up horizontally. I will look into a RelativeLayout though.

Comment: What are you trying to do? That xml will create a button on the left and a TextView on its right

Comment: I want the button to be on the left of the screen and the textview on the right. This creates a button and textview on the left side of the screen

Comment: Then you should use a RelativeLayout, this is what it is for: it has attribute to align things relative to their parent or other things. Anyway why the layout_gravity attribute? Maybe you meant gravity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lik Gil said, you can use this way :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="@style/calibrate_button"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="New Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        style="@style/calibrate_text"
        android:text="@string/calibrate"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: As I commented above, I don't know how the OP use this layout, but `layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` here is not needed. This will center the layout in the parent (and there is not parent in this example). To center the buttons *inside* the layout, use `gravity="center_horizontal"`

Comment: He said that he wants to justify a TextView wich is in Linear Layout nested in a parent Linear Layout.