# Evenly spread out multiline text across the screen

Tags: android, xml, layout, eula

Theres this one page in my app which shows EULA

Heres a sample :

```
This license provides you with limited rights to use the Software. The Owner retains all ownership, right, title and interest in, to and of the Software and all copies of it. All rights not specifically granted in this license, including domestic and international copyrights, are reserved by the Owner.
```

Now, the page that displays this content will take up whole of display on device screen.
However, its left justified. What I want is to fill in the gaps such that it doesnt look like theres something remaining at the end.

is there any attribute for that ?

Comment: Just so I'm understanding this correctly, you want your text to appear like the example in the left in this picture: http://webstyleguide.com/wsg3/figures/8-typography/8-7-650.jpg ?

Comment: @Patr3xion thats exactly what I want . from the 1st pic.

Comment: I will provide an answer for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android TextView Justify Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text). Android does not support full justification, but if you scroll down from the first answer and you will see a few workaround that should solve your problem.