# How to make EditText Hint right to left -sided?

Tags: android, android-edittext, hint

How to make EditText Hint right to left -sided

I write Arabic word hint ,, and its showing on the left side .

Comment: Look at this answer it has some detailed explanation 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text

Comment: this answer fortext justify ... its not related

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this one:
Use `android:gravity="right"`

Comment: <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username_edtx"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:ems="11"
            android:hint="Write your hint text"
         
           android:gravity="right"
          
            android:singleLine="true"
         />

Comment: Try this it work in my code. Let me know if not work

Comment: @MaherIsmaail How is your layout:width property set ?

Comment: I just use the wrap_content

Comment: thanks I was using    android:layout_gravity="right"

Answer (score 9):

try to use attributes

```
android:textDirection="locale"
android:textAlignment="viewStart"
```

It works for me

Comment: This also works for me but only at runtime, not in the Android Studio design view using the option "Preview Right to Left".

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to resolve your problem:

```
        myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (myEditText.getText().toString().length() > 0 & myEditText.getGravity() != Gravity.LEFT) {
                myEditText.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            } else if (myEditText.getText().toString().length() == 0 & myEditText.getGravity() != Gravity.RIGHT) {
                myEditText.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use android:gravity to change the position of your text in side the EditText container. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html) you can find more about Gravity.

For example

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Your hint here"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:id="@+id/editText" />
```

Comment: Well if I understood your question clearly, you are looking for the EditText container layout to be from right to left, in that case you can change the layout width and check. The above answer I gave you works for me. But if you are looking for the end of the screen layout, you can change it using: android:layout_gravity="end".